# Using ffsave and ffload from package ff

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, ff

I have problem with *.ff files when I ffsave use ffload in R.
When I use `ffsave(fileName)` I see the `fileName.ffData` and `fileName.RData`.

My question are:

1. Are the `*.ff` created somewhere when I use `ffsave` or after I use `ffload(fileName)`?
2. Can I delete `*.ff` files once I see them?
3. Can I control where to store `*.ff` files?

Can anyone teach me a proper way to use `ffsave` and `ffload` to remove `*.ff` because they are big files?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/ff.pdf)? By default normally the files are saved on the working directory, check in the folder of `getwd()`.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to question 3: Can I control where to store *.ff files?

ff files are by default saved in `getOption("fftempdir")`. You can change this by changing that option

```
require(ff)
getOption("fftempdir")
[1] "/tmp/RtmpkneHQo"
options(fftempdir = "/home/janw")
x <- ff(1:10)
filename(x)
[1] "/home/janw/ff12153b63d8c1.ff"
list.files("/home/janw", pattern = ".ff")
[1] "ff12153b63d8c1.ff"
```

Answer to question 2: Can I delete *.ff files once I see them?
Of course you *can* but you might be loosing data which you are using in an R process (every ff object is backed by an .ff file - so if you remove that file, you no longer have the data). But if you have `ffsaved` the data somewhere, you can safely remove the .ff files as you can load the data again using `ffload`. See answer to question 1.

Answer to question 1: Are the *.ff created somewhere when I use ffsave or after I use ffload(fileName)? u 
The .ff files were already on your disk before you called ffsave. What ffsave does is simply zipping the .ff files of the specified objects you indicated to save in a directory. Once you have done this, you can safely remove the .ff files as you can reload them using ffload.

```
ffsave(x, file = "/home/janw/mydata")
[1] "  adding: home/janw/ff12153b63d8c1.ff (deflated 35%)"
list.files("/home/janw", pattern = ".ff$")
[1] "ff12153b63d8c1.ff"
list.files("/home/janw", pattern = "mydata")
[1] "mydata.ffData" "mydata.RData" 

## Now what happens if we remove the .ff file of the x variable - it is no longer accessible
file.remove("/home/janw/ff12153b63d8c1.ff")
x[1:2]
opening ff /home/janw/ff12153b63d8c1.ff
Error: file.access(filename, 0) == 0 is not TRUE

## And we are ffloading the data back
ffload("/home/janw/mydata", overwrite=TRUE)
[1] "home/janw/ff12153b63d8c1.ff"
## Waw, it is back!
list.files("/home/janw", pattern = ".ff$")
[1] "ff12153b63d8c1.ff"
## And we can access it again.
x[1:2]
opening ff /home/janw/ff12153b63d8c1.ff
[1] 1 2
```

When ffsaving, you will have a file with extension .ffData and one with .RData. The .ffData file contains the raw .ff files, the .RData file contains the virtual part (levels of factors e.g. and links to the raw .ff files)

Comment: Please tell me what is wrong with the following code.  Thanks. getOption("fftempdir")
[1] "/tmp/RtmpORDd7N"
getwd()
[1] "/u/home/eeskin/yujulee"
options(fftempdir = "/u/home/eeskin/yujulee/project")
x <- ff(1:10)
Error in setwd(dfile) : cannot change working directory

Comment: The directory you specified does not exist on your computer. You need to specify a directory which exists of course.